# groupby mean и median

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, анализ-данных, aggregate

Имеется датафрейм:

```
df.head()

     title    birthday     today      age
0   Group 1  1997-07-24  2020-05-04 8320 days
1   Group 1  1997-07-24  2020-05-04 8320 days
2   Group 1  1997-07-24  2020-05-04 8320 days
3   Group 1  1997-07-24  2020-05-04 8320 days
4   Group 1  1997-07-24  2020-05-04 8320 days

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 329739 entries, 0 to 350675
Data columns (total 4 columns):
title       329739 non-null object
birthday    329739 non-null datetime64[ns]
today       329739 non-null datetime64[ns]
age         329739 non-null timedelta64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), object(1), timedelta64[ns](1)
memory usage: 22.6+ MB
```

Мне необходимо узнать максимальный, минимальный, средний и медианный возраст на каждом курсе. 
Но применение

```
df[['age', 'title']].groupby('title').agg(['max', 'min', 'mean', 'median'])
```

Выдает ошибку

> ```
> ValueError: no results
> ```

Однако считаются максимальные и минимальные значения, а также mean и median без группировки:

```
df['age'].median()

Timedelta('10684 days 00:00:00')
```

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что тип данных `timedelta64[ns]` - нечисловой и поэтому Pandas не позволяет делать агрегирование. Поэтому можно сначала создать виртуальный числовой столбец (например вычленить число дней из `timedelta64[ns]`) и тогда уже делать арифметику с ним:

```
In [51]: (df
          .assign(days=df["age"].dt.days)
          .groupby('title')
          ["days"]
          .agg(['max', 'min', 'mean', 'median']))
Out[51]:
          max   min  mean  median
title
Group 1  8320  8320  8320    8320
```

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо) Все получилось) А для новичка поясните, пожалуйста, что конкретно Вы сделали?

Comment: @RustemNagimov, дополнил ответ)

Comment: @MaxU, когда `timedelta64[ns]` - нечисловой, почему `df['age'].median()` работает?

Comment: @MarianD, похоже в `DataFrameGroupBy.mean()` / `SeriesGroupBy.mean()` есть дополнительные проверки по сравнению с `DataFrame.mean()` / `Series.mean()`

Comment: @MaxU, значит, `timedelta64[ns]` нет нечисловым, а числовым, и — следовательно — объяснение в вашем ответе нет совсем правильным. Когда вы знаете более конкретно, какие дополнительные проверки применяются, напишите о них, пожалуйста, мне это интересно для будущего.

Comment: @MarianD, timedelta - не является числовым типом данных

Comment: @MaxU, тогда как возможно сделать `mean()` с нечисловым типом данных? В конце концов, ˙timedelta64[ns]˙ - количество наносекунд. По моему, проблема в чем-то другом, я не знаю, в чем, потому спросил вас об обьяснение «дополнительной проверки».

Comment: @MarianD, если хотите разобраться почему работает именно так - задайте новый вопрос ;)

Comment: @MaxU, я что-то прочитал / попробовал и написал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1124162/233990) с другим подходом.

Answer (score 2):

Короткое решение (одно из возможных) - примените методы **серии**:

```
df[['age', 'title']].groupby('title').agg(['max', 'min', pd.Series.mean, pd.Series.median])
```

---

Результат:

> ```
>                                                 age
>                max        min       mean     median
>   title                 
> Group 1  8320 days  8320 days  8320 days  8320 days
> ```

---

*Анализ проблемы и объяснение:*

Многие методы класса `DataFrame` имеют ключевой параметр `numeric_only`; *у метод класса `Series` такого параметра нет*.

*Примеры таких методов:* Все, которые вы применили: [`.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html), [`.min()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html), [`.mean()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), [`.median()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.median.html).

Параметр `numeric_only` определяет столбцы, ко которым метод будет приниматься. У него  3 возможные значения:

- `None` (стандартное значение) - то же самое, как `False`,
- `True` - только столбцы типа `int`, `float` и `bool`,
- `False` - все столбцы, для которых метод умеет работать.

При применении методов класса `DataFrame` к объектам типа `DataFrameGroupBy` (ваш случай) используется индивидуальное значение параметра `numeric_only` в зависимости от конкретного метода, например в вашем случае:

- для метода `.max()`: стандартное значение (`None`),
- для метода `.min()`: стандартное значение (`None`),
- для метода `.mean()`: `.mean(numeric_only=True)`
- для метода `.median()`: `.median(numeric_only=True)`

Вы применяете эти 4 методы для вашего столбца `'age'`, который типа ни `int`, ни `float`, ни `bool`. Значит, он будет исключен из применения методов `.mean()` и `.median()`, что мешает сделать комплектный результат в виде таблицы со всеми 4 вами требуемыми столбцами и выдает ошибку

> ```
> ValueError: no results
> ```

---

Как это обойти — несколько примеров:

1. Применить методы класса `Series`, которые работают всегда, когда возможно

   - прямо (как я это сделал в начале ответа):

     ```
     df[['age', 'title']].groupby('title').agg(['max', 'min',
                                                pd.Series.mean, pd.Series.median])
     ```
   - использованием этой идеи для вами созданной или ламбда функции, например

     ```
     def my_mean(series):
         return series.mean()

     df[['age', 'title']].groupby('title').agg(['max', 'min',
                                                my_mean,
                                                lambda s: s.median()])
     ```
2. Использованием методов класса `DataFrame` с параметром `numeric_only=False` для создания (и в последствии применения) собственной функций, например так:

   ```
   from functools import partial

   my_mean   = partial(pd.DataFrame.mean,   numeric_only=False)
   my_median = partial(pd.DataFrame.median, numeric_only=False)

   df[['age', 'title']].groupby('title').agg(['max', 'min', my_mean, my_median])
   ```
3. Использовать функции NumPy (ведь это в заднем плане делает сам pandas - *всегда,* и в предыдущих двух пунктах), но *косвенно, чтобы pandas это «не заметил»,* например:

   ```
   def my_mean(x):
        return np.mean(x)

   my_median = lambda x: np.median(x)

   df[['age', 'title']].groupby('title').agg(['max', 'min', my_mean, my_median])
   ```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за ответ)

Comment: @Rustem, не стоит.:-)

Comment: Можете пояснить фразу «все столбцы; когда это невозможно, то как True» ? Что значит «то как True” в конце?

Comment: @MaxU, первая попытка — все столбцы. Но когда бы на хотя один **не** int, float или bool  столбец метод не мог бы применен, тогда в результате будут только int, float и bool  столбцы. Другими словами или все, или только int, float, bool, ничего между тем.

Comment: интересно как вы пришли к тому что `"При применении методов класса DataFrame к объектам типа DataFrameGroupBy (ваш случай) используется индивидуальное значение параметра numeric_only в зависимости от конкретного метода"`? Вы нашли подтверждение этому в исходном коде?

Comment: @MaxU, да может быть. Или дедукцией, или опытом, или пробованием, я не помню, я с тем встретился уже давно. Я думаю, что и для вас это ничего нового.

Comment: я не согласен с высказыванием `"используется индивидуальное значение параметра numeric_only в зависимости от конкретного метода"` - по-моему там вызываются разные функции в случае `DataFrame.mean()` и в случае `DataFrameGroupBy.mean()`

Comment: @MaxU, оба `DataFrameGroupBy.mean()` и `DataFrame.mean()` вызывают ту же самую функцию `_cython_agg_general()` и передают ее (тоже) значение параметра `numeric_only`, но определение `DataFrameGroupBy.mean()` такое: `def median(self, numeric_only=True):`, пока для `DataFrame.mean()` такое: `def mean(self, axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs):` - как видно, стандартное значения для параметра `numeric_only` являются разными.

Comment: Это уже больше похоже на правду :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107975/discussion-between-mariand-and-maxu).